# Redshift unload terminates when called by sqlalchemy

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I'm running a few large UNLOAD queries from Redshift to S3 from a python script using SQLAlchemy. (along with the sqlalchemy-redshift package)
The first couple work but the last, which runs the longs (~30 minutes) is marked Terminated in the Redshift Query Dashboard.  Some data is loaded to S3 but I suspect it's not ALL of it.
I'm fairly confident the query itself works because I've used it to download locally in the past.

Does SQLAlchemy close queries that take too long?  Is there a way to set or lengthen the query-timeout?  The script itself continues as if nothing went wrong and the Redshift logs don't indicate a problem either but when a query is marked Terminated it usually means something external has killed the process.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where you can control timeouts in Redshift:

1. In the workload manager console, you get an option to specify timeout for each queue.
2. The ODBC/ JDBC driver settings. Update your registry based on the steps in the link below,
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be more an issue with sqlalchemy than AWS/Redshift.

SQLAlchemy does not implicitly "Commit Transactions" so if the connection is closed while uncommitted transactions are still open (even if the query itself appears to be finished), all transactions within that connection are marked Terminated.

Solution is to finish your connection or each transaction with "commit transaction;"

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute("""SELECT .... """)
conn.execute("""COMMIT TRANSACTION""")
```